# How do I set a global configuration variable everywhere in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, variables

I have an application that will eventually be open-sourced. Currently it runs on my own domain, but I want to set the domain to be a variable that can be changed. Basically after declaring:

```
foo = ENV['DOMAIN_NAME'] || 'example.com'
```

I want to be able to do reference it in:

1. Views
2. Configuration
3. Controllers
4. Helpers

Optionally: Can i set up a configuration file somewhere that holds all my globally declared variables, and then reference them everywhere? This would allow me to make a `config.rb.sample` file that I can ask users to fill their settings in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Figaro. It's really really good and easy to use. You don't need any configuration for it whatsoever, you add the gem in your Gemfile, bundle and that's it!

To store your variables you need to create a new file in `config/application.yml` and then store them like:

```
# Global
#
aws_access_key: ~
aws_secret_key: ~
aws_s3_host: 's3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com'

rails_secret: 'ce223735d819fb993466ac5e615fff07cc71c19db40e211b83a3ac579203fcf4db78251f4143025e99aabffb1ea46bd252b7b16e50c4c88e5407b42fe5d4e6c4'
devise_secret: '9c1fdc65b9f385c54c99e1a81ea398269749f12eee6790c12921dcf1ba7579864ef0fe40f8bcf33d2d78fcbbb506573f5a0c864090de9f3fd991f8367c2aee7c'

# Per Environment
#

development:
  domain: 'lvh.me:3000'

production:
  domain: ~

  # Puma
  #
  max_threads: 5
  web_concurency: 2
```

And to access them you simply call `Figaro.env.rails_secret` or `ENV['rails_secret']` :)

More info: https://github.com/laserlemon/figaro

Answer (score 2):

I'm really happy with a combination of [the global gem](https://github.com/railsware/global) and [the dotenv gem](https://github.com/bkeepers/dotenv). The first one would be for global configuration, and the second one for storing the environment variables.

Your global `.yml` files would contain reference to your environment variables (such as the one you put above: `ENV['DOMAIN_NAME'])` that would actually be defined in your `.env` file.